# Issue in Opening IE in full screen using java script on secondary Monitor

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, window.open, window.opener

I am trying to open full screen IE on secondary monitor using following code.

```
var NewWindow= window.open('sample.html', 'new window', "left=911, top=0,titlebar=0,fullscreen=1");
```

but no luck, full screen IE always open on same monitor, Even i tried using moveto function , no help at all.

Also i tried below code also

```
var NewWindow= window.open('sample.html', 'new window', "left=911, top=0,titlebar=0,channelmode=1");
```

here windows open in full screen with title bar[i dont require title bar], on using option like titlebar=no didn't hepl it.

Is there any alternative solution available.

Note: i was using IE11 browser.

Comment: even tried using webkitRequestFullScreen , it works only from where click even generated :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this

```
 Window.open("urltoopen", "_blank", "location=yes, fullscreen=yes, menubar=no, toolbar=no, status=yes, scrollbars=yes");
```

Comment: on using fullscreen=yes, new window always open on where click event originated. In my case its always laptop but i wan to open the new IE tab in Secondary screen[HDMI] in full screen